Regex Pattern to Mask Field with Commas in Java
I am working on a Java application that processes strings. I need to mask the content of a specific field. The challenge I'm facing is that this field sometimes contains commas, which interferes with my current masking pattern. Here is what I have so far:
Current regex pattern
field\s*=\s*([^,]*)

Example

field=I'm graduated from Comsats, Sahiwal,

Current output

field=******, Sahiwal,

Desired output

field=******,

Question
How can I construct a regex pattern in Java that properly masks the entire content of the field, stopping at that comma that indicates the end of the field? It should handle commas within the field value.

how is the "comma that indicates the end of the field" identified? In your last example, how I know that "name=John Doe" is not part of the field?

In the middle of your post there are some examples that include braces, and apparently you don't want them to be part of a value, but there is no clarification about this in your post. What exactly are all the delimiters of your input format, and how would those characters be specified if they needed to be part of the value itself? For instance, how would a literal = or } be encoded so it is not interpreted as a delimiter?

We need to see multiple fields, or a complete set of input, to understand a safe means of distinguishing them.  I suspect the answer is to use a few lines of code, rather than trying to do it all with one regular expression.

You might use:
\bfield\s*=\s*[^,=\s]+(?:[\s,](?!\s*\w+=)\s*[^,=\s]+)*(?:,\s*$)?

The pattern matches:

\bfield\s*=\s* Match the word field followed by = between optional whitespace chars
[^,=\s]+ Match 1 or more non whitespace chars other than , or =
(?: Non capture group

[\s,] Match either a whitespace char or ,
(?!\s*\w+=)
\s*[^,=\s]+ Match optional whitespace chars followed 1 or more by a non whitespace chars other than , or =


)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
(?:,\s*$)? Optionally match a comma followed by optional whitespace chars till the end of the string

See a regex demo and a Java demo
Note that \s could also match a newline.
For example:
String regex = "\\bfield\\s*=\\s*[^,=\\s]+(?:[\\s,](?!\\s*\\w+=)\\s*[^,=\\s]+)*(?:,\\s*$)?";
String string = "field=I'm graduated from Comsats, Sahiwal,\n"
 + "field=Some text, name=John Doe, id=12345,\n"
 + "field=Some, text, name=John Doe, id=12345,\n";

String subst = "field=*****";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);

Output
field=*****
field=*****, name=John Doe, id=12345,
field=*****, name=John Doe, id=12345,


You could use a look-ahead assertion to see that what follows a current comma is not yet the name of a next field (followed by =):
\bfield\s*=\s*((?:,(?!\s*\w+\s*=)|[^,}])*)

Here it is assumed that the names of fields only have alphanumerical characters (and possibly an underscore).

Well considering that the input data is enclosed within curly braces, this solution might not work completely, as [^,] will also match the closing }. Maybe [^,}]? Though if OP actually has values that includes } then, i think they are just asking for trouble

Yes, good remark: updated to exclude the closing brace. Indeed, the asker has not explained anything about escaping mechanisms for including delimiters literally, like also =.
